# How can i obtain in C# a specific operator's function?

Tags: c#, function, f#, operator-overloading

Is it possible to obtain the function behind a C# operator? 
For example in F# you can do

```
let add = (+);;

val add : (int -> int -> int)
```

Is it possible in c# to do something like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> add = (+);
```

or

```
Func<int, int, int> add = Int32.(+)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lambda expressions:

```
Func<int, int, int> func = (val1, val2) => val1 + val2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an indirect way to do what you want:

```
Func<int, int, int> add = (int a, int b) => a + b;
```

When reflected, it can be seen that F# doesn't access the `Int32.operator+` directly either (that's probably impossible), but does something like the C# code above just using an internal delegate type instead (`Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FastFunc`).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, addition of `int`s is done by the CIL `add` instruction, rather than a method call, so there isn't any sense in which it would be possible to acquire 'the actual `MethodInfo`'.